# Do VPNs have upstream ISPs that log traffic (making VPN claims of having strict no-log policies pointless)?

Tags: vpn, anonymity, deanonymization

Most VPNs claim to adhere to a strict no-log policy, but these claims are typically unproven and/or even downright false. For instance, if the VPN says they collect absolutely no logs, how will they know whether a subscriber has used all of the bandwidth allocated per month or when the subscriber needs to renew a monthly or yearly plan? These considerations make VPN claims of enforcing strict no-logging policies laughably dishonest at best, not to mention the many times when supposedly "no-log" VPNs have handed over subscriber info to data harvesters and determined global adversaries.

But even if VPNs are telling the truth about not keeping any logs, don't VPNs also have ISPs upstream from the VPN itself and won't these upper-tier ISPs log traffic between clients, lower-tier ISPs and the VPN?

Comment: Answered my question. Stay away from VPNs, at least for anonymity purposes.